# Specific Java date Datatype

Tags: java, types

I want to use this timestamp value

```
2010-02-09T04:05:20.777+0000
```

with the Datatype DateFormat or SampleDateFormat for the sending of Events in Esper

```
cepRT.sendEvent(new Comments("LOL", 529591, 0, " ", 0, 0, 2010-02-09T04:05:20.777+0000));
```

But the compiler prints me an Error.
Can you please help me how to handle it

Comment: What's the compiler error? Why are you passing the timestamp as a literal? I would've thought it should look more like `new Comments("LOL", 529591, 0, " ", 0, 0, DateFormat("2010-02-09T04:05:20.777+0000"))`

Comment: I would have thought that one of the dedicated time objects (`LocalDateTime`, `java.sql.Date`, etc) would be a better choice (depending on your ultimate goals). Are you trying to format the value or parse it?

Comment: @MadProgrammer I want to make a EPL-Query e.g. date>2010-02-09T04:05:20.777+0000. It is Compatible with a String? Because in your Case it prints me an Error, Then I correct it with converting to a string